# Is there anything similar to ASP.NET Master Page in PHP or HTML/CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I've worked worked with visual studio for a while and one thing which impressed me was the master pages. Is there anything similar to it in PHP or can it be achieved using simple HTML and CSS?

Comment: Not familiar with Master Page, but there are a large number of frameworks available for PHP. I suggest investigating ones like Symphony and Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a master page, but there are template engines like smarty that provide similar functionality. You can create template files with content place-holders that can be filled by php. Smarty also provides extra tools that can provide a more complex functionality for your templates.

But with php, templates are only an option. Every output of the script goes into the browser. Template systems only help in separating the logic from the output.